# Meteor data not inserting or displaying after removing insecure package

Tags: meteor, meteorite

Data is not getting inserted into the database after i removed autopublish and insecure packages. Please let me know what i am missing.

Userdata = new Meteor.Collection("Userdata");

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.sample.events({
           "click button.clickeve": function (){
           var e_value = $('input[name = "exampleInputEmail1"]').val();
           var e_name = $('input[name = "exampleInputName"]').val();
           doc = {user_id: Meteor.userId(), e_value:e_value, e_name:e_name}
        }
    });
    Template.temp.list_item = function(){
        return Userdata.find();
    }
    Meteor.subscribe("Userdata");
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish("Userdata", function() {
        return Userdata.find();
    });
    Userdata.allow({
            insert: function(userID,doc) {
            return userID === doc.user_id;
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Can you paste the code where you define `Userdata`?

Comment: @MrD I have edited my code now. I created the collecton Userdata but not pasted the entire code over there.Waiting for suggestion...

Answer (score 3):

You don't have an insert statement.

```
Userdata = new Meteor.Collection("Userdata");

if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish("Userdata", function() {
        return Userdata.find();
    });
    Userdata.allow({
            insert: function(userID,doc) {
            return userID === doc.user_id;
            }
        });
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.sample.events({
           "click button.clickeve": function (e){
           e.preventDefault(); // to prevent default action of the button
           var e_value = $('input[name = "exampleInputEmail1"]').val();
           var e_name = $('input[name = "exampleInputName"]').val();
           doc = {user_id: Meteor.userId(), e_value:e_value, e_name:e_name};
           Userdata.insert(doc); // actually inserting the document
        }
    });
    Template.temp.list_item = function(){
        return Userdata.find();
    }
    Meteor.subscribe("Userdata");
}
```

Comment: sry for that. I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: It says [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer), you can mark an answer as accepted without reputation if you are the OP. Marking an answer as accepted will actually give you +2 reputation.